# Print Previous & New Word using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to, as the title says, use Scanner to first print both words that are entered. After that, I need to ask for another word, and then print the last word from the first two, and the next one that is entered. Here is what I have tried:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("TYPE MANY WORDS, ONE PER LINE:");

  String prev = in.next();

  while(in.hasNext())
  {
    String word = in.next();

    System.out.println(prev);

    System.out.println(word); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For subsequent iterations you will need to assign something to `prev`

try

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("TYPE MANY WORDS, ONE PER LINE:");

String prev = in.next();

  while(in.hasNext())
  {
    String word = in.next();
    System.out.println(prev);
    System.out.println(word); 

    prev = word;

    if (word.equals ("q")) break;
  }
```

Comment: glad to hear, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("TYPE MANY WORDS, ONE PER LINE:");

  String prev = in.next();

  while(in.hasNext())
  {
    String word = in.next();

    System.out.println(prev);

    System.out.println(word);

    prev = word; 
  }
```

You need to store the previous word.